How to compute the cumulative sum of a list in terraform?
Is it possible to use terraform to compute the cumulative sum of a list? There is the sum function, but I am looking for the cumulative sum.
Example:
locals {
  numbers_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}

The desired output would be: [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

The equivalent python code would be:
from numpy import cumsum

print(cumsum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

It prints: [ 1  3  6 10 15]

You can use a combination of range and slice functions to get the desired result:

range(max): generates a list of numbers using a start value (from 0 to max - 1)
slice: extracts some consecutive elements from within a list

Example:
locals {
  values  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  indexes = range(length(local.values)) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

  cumulative_sum_list = [
    for i in local.indexes :
    # For each index, sum the numbers from the start of the list to the current index
    sum(slice(local.values, 0, i + 1))
  ]
}

output "cumulative_sum_list" {
  value       = local.cumulative_sum_list
  description = "The cumulative sum of the values in the list"
}

Running terraform plan:
Changes to Outputs:
  + cumulative_sum_list = [
      + 1,
      + 3,
      + 6,
      + 10,
      + 15,
    ]


I think you can avoid the separate local.indexes by using the two-symbol form of for expression: [ for i, n in local.values : ...]. That will set i to the current index and n to the current element value. (You can then ignore n, because it isn't actually needed for this expression anyway.)
